# Spring REST Data

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data, dependency-management, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to expose Spring REST Data using a demo application found in the documentation:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

By using the dependencies found in the example, I'm unable to find the RepositoryRestResource:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Following Netbeans advice, I've added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>

    <type>jar</type>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Now the code compiles, however the execution fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/rest/core/invoke/RepositoryInvokerFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2570)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:534)
```

Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to remove the additional dependency as Spring Boot's REST starter already pulls in all dependencies in the correct versions.

Spring Boot 1.2.3 refers to the Spring Data train Evans in its second service release. This boils down to Spring Data REST 2.2.2. If you want to upgrade to a newer release train (e.g. Fowler), change the value of the `spring-data-releasetrain.version` property to `Fowler-GA`. That will then upgrade Spring Data REST to 2.3.0 and also make sure you get all required dependencies in matching versions.

Comment: Thanks it seems an issue with Netbeans environment. By compiling with the maven shell it worked.